# Ignoring PHP messages with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm just wondering if there's a way to bypass all the PHP-messages when echoing the response back with json_decode.

My current problem is that if my PHP code has any echos or anything else that is included in the output except for the array my Javascript simply doesn't work.

PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
$errors = array();
$data = [];
// data from angular to be handled and 
// then if all goes well set submission to true to display with ng-show
$data["submission"] = true;
header('Content-Type:application/json;');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

JS:

```
$scope.testProcessForm = function() {
        $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'reg.php',
      data    : $scope.formData,
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
     })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.submission = response.data.submission;

        }, function(error) {
           console.log('error', error);
```

I assumed that by using response.data.submission I'd be able to just access that data inside there but as mentioned above, the code breaks if any PHP output is included that isn't in an array.

Is it possible to *just* access/respond the $data array so that it doesn't break?

Comment: You should use `error_log` instead of `echo` to print out debug information / errors. Using `error_log` will put the messages to your `php_error_logs` file.

Comment: How about not outputting any superfluous messages in PHP and ensuring you're outputting actual valid JSON...!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean output with `ob_clean` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) before call last echo:

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
// you also need to add ob_start()
ob_start();
$errors = array();
$data = [];
// data from angular to be handled and 
// then if all goes well set submission to true to display with ng-show
$data["submission"] = true;
header('Content-Type:application/json;');
ob_clean();
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> `error_reporting();` should be set to `0` => `error_reporting(0);`

Also note that all the possible conditions which can cause error should be handled grammatically and you can send error code(*using `http_response_code(404/500)`*) with the response which could be read at client side.

Answer (score 1):

```
error_reporting(0);
```

rather than

```
error_reporting(1);
```

Comment: It still displays my echos from my PHP code :( does that mean that I have to remove all the echos?

Comment: Ah sorry - I misunderstood and thought you were just trying to suppress errors. I would probably suggest avoiding echoing things. If you _need_ to render output in this manner, consider starting a variable called `$output` or similar and appending output to it `$output .= 'your stuff';` then you can echo it when need be without it popping up when you don't want it.